# Open links in Safari from WKWebView versus webView in iOS10+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios10, openurl

I've found many useful posts on the subject on how openURL is now deprecated in iOS10+. But it took me a while to get it implemented correctly in my project.

**This was NOT working for me (using WKWebView), but this is how I had it in my existing code**:

```
- (BOOL)WKWebView:(UIWebView *)WKWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        ...code to handle open url...
}
```

**But, this DID work for me (using webView):**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        ...code to handle open url...
}
```

Why is this? My app's target deployment is 8.0 if that matters and I still have code to support the older "openURL" method.

Also, according to documentation, [I **should** be using WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview).

Comment: If you are looking just to show some web pages, `SFSafariViewController` might be the way to go: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

For`WKWebView` you should use `navigationDelegate`.
About `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` you can write:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```